# Проблемы с запуском простого приложения на tornado

Tags: python, http, urllib, tornado

При запуске простого приложения:

```
import tornado.web
from tornadio import server

from handler import BroadcastHandler

urls = [ (r"/", BroadcastHandler) ]

application = tornado.web.Application( urls )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    server.SocketServer(application)
```

Возникают следующие ошибки:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "serv.py", line 2, in <module>
    from tornadio import server
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tornadio/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from tornadio.router import get_router
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tornadio/router.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tornadio import persistent, polling, session
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tornadio/polling.py", line 17, in <module>
    from urllib import unquote
ImportError: cannot import name 'unquote'
```

В интернете пишут, что при возникновении такой ошибки можно попробовать заменить `from urllib import unquote` на `from urllib.parse import unquote`
.

Помогите разобраться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка не в вашем приложении, а в библиотеке `tornadio`. Согласно https://github.com/mrjoes/tornadio библиотека уже 5 лет не обновлялась, что может навести на мысли о том, что она несовместима с Python3. Данное исключение возникает именно из-за несовместимости - в Py3 модуль urllib был реорганизован. Можно заменить в `polling.py` 17 строку на `from urllib.parse import unquote`, но запустить все равно не выйдет, потому что это не единственная проблема.

А если нужны Websockets, то в Tornado они уже реализованы в модуле `tornado.websocket`.